# How to get object.isXXX() value in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, pojo

I have a POJO class with `boolean isActive()` method.

I want to use it inside freemarker like this `${task.active?string}` but I get

```
Expression task.active is undefined
```

Is there any way to use this method or do I have to add `boolean getActive()` to my POJO?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the primitive `boolean` type? For me `boolean isActive()` works fine, but the boxed variant `Boolean isActive()` produces the error you mentioned above.

Comment: Turned out it was a type :) Still, good to know that `Boolean` is treated differently than `boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a JavaBean property (and it looks like one), then it should be available as `task.active`. After all, FreeMarker just uses the standard JavaBeans API to query what properties are available. There are a few things that can cause problems here, however... One is that Chaquotay has mentioned, i.e., `Boolean` instead of `boolean` (the JavaBeans spec says it's not the same). Another is when `task` implements the `Map` interface, in which case, if the wrapper has `simpleMapWrapper` set to `true`, FreeMarker only exposes the map keys.